# Meaning of kisses in "Le fabuleux destin d'Amélie Poulain"

Tags: plot-explanation, amelie

At the end of [Le fabuleux destin d'Amélie Poulain](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0211915) (2001), Amélie gives Nino three kisses in very specific places (cheek, neck and eyelids) and silently asks Nino to do the same to her.

Do these kisses have any special meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a bit speculative answer but le me try:

- A kiss on the cheek is a sign of [friendship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheek_kissing). So Amélie says that Nino is her friend.
- A kiss on the neck is [intimate and sensual](https://www.femina.in/relationships/love-sex/types-of-kisses-and-their-meaning-199254.html#neck-kiss), and it is often a part of a foreplay. This suggest that Amélie is treating Nino as a lover.
- A kiss on the eyelids means ["devotion"](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-when-he-kisses-my-eyes)  - this means that Amélie loves and cares about Nino.

So by kissing Nino in this special way, Amélie says: "I love you, I want you, you are my soulmate". Then she asks Nino for similar declaration.